# What's wrong with this c++ code

Tags: c++, debugging

I'm a beginner learning code, and I was copying what a YouTube video for programming teaching said. But when I wrote the code, it resulted in some errors.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 
int main()
{
    int num1 , num2;

    cout<< " Enter number 1 and number 2 \n";
    cin>> num1 >> num2;

    if (num1 == num2);
        cout<< "The both numbers are equal \n";

    else if (num1> num2)
        cout<< "Number 1 is greater than number 2 \n";
    else (num1< num2)
        cout<< "Number 2 is greater than number 1 \n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post your error message as well.

Answer (score 8):

Note that `;` means the expression ends, so you should change

```
if (num1 == num2);
```

to

```
if (num1 == num2)
```

And `else` doesn't need condition, so change

```
else (num1< num2)
```

to

```
else
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You dont need `;` after `if` condition check
2. If you want to do a condition check, you should use `else if`, in that case  `else` is not enough:

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std; 
   int main()
   {
       int num1 , num2;

       cout<< " Enter number 1 and number 2 \n";
       cin>> num1 >> num2;

       if (num1 == num2)
           cout<< "The both numbers are equal \n";
       else if (num1> num2)
           cout<< "Number 1 is greater than number 2 \n";
       else if (num1< num2)
           cout<< "Number 2 is greater than number 1 \n";  
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: I pasted your code instead and those errors came out too..



------ Build started: Project: Test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
  FirstProgram.cpp
c:\documents and settings\general\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\firstprogram.cpp(8): error C2601: 'main' : local function definitions are illegal
          c:\documents and settings\general\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\firstprogram.cpp(4): this line contains a '{' which has not yet been matched
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Answer (score 1):

```
;   is not placed after `if` condition
```

Moreover, else does not get a condition... it always checks the negation of its corresponding if.
 In fact if the condition of `if` does not hold the code in the block of `else` is executed.... by changing

```
 else (num1< num2)
        cout<< "Number 2 is greater than number 1 \n";
```

to

```
 else
        cout<< "Number 2 is greater than number 1 \n";
```

your problem will get solved.